# Child component has wrong value for 'window.location.href' after redirect -- the value is needed to make icons work

Tags: javascript, angular

i have an icon component that gets the SVG paths using

```
   get absUrl() {
    return window.location.href.split('#')[0];
  }
```

but the issue is if you land on a page that's not 'found' and a redirect happens
the icons stop working and inspecting the code shows that the URL that it slapped into place for each icon is the wrong url
for example looking for 'dashboard' icon on a 'login' page that does not exist
the url is

```
 https://localhost:4200/login#dashboard
```

but i'm on page

```
https://localhost:4200/404
```

so the link should be

```
https://localhost:4200/404#dashboard
```

any ideas how to keep this in sync? with the page  that I'm on?

Otherwise all my icons stop working once a redirect to /404 happens due to a page not being found?

## EDIT:

Here's how the absUrl is used on the component template:

```
<svg
  version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  [style.fill]="color ? color : ''"
  [style.width]="size"
  [style.height]="size"
>
  <use [attr.xlink:href]="absUrl + '#' + name"></use>
</svg>
```

## EDIT 2

As a temporary workaround, I configured my redirect for 404 from:

```
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '404'},
```

to

```
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },
```

But then people could link to routes that don't exist so I'm trying to run a redirect from the component itself if it detect that the route is not '404'.

This does not work when called in the constructor, ngOnInit or even ngOnViewInit

But, if called anywhere, including the constructor, inside a setTimeout with 0ms -- this will work and render properly.

```
constructor(public router: Router) {
    if (window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.length - 3) !== '404') {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['404']);
      }, 0);
    }
  }
```

Which makes me think this is some rendering bug with Angular itself. It's a bit hacky and unexplainable but works...

Comment: Ah no worries, appreciate you trying to help though

Comment: What is the _actual_ value of location.href in those “problematic situations”? What is the result of absPath, and how is it used? That will indicate if the “issue” is with the split or unrelated/elsewhere.

Comment: @user2864740 I've added the code on how this is actually being used on the frontend. 

Why have you voted to close this?

Comment: also the result of abs path  logged on the console from the component as well as how it is used in the component is the url that was not found. If you go to /asdasd -- the value will remain /asdsada although you've been redirected to /404 due to angular routing configuration for path '**'

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: Did you try a timeout?

Comment: @Nikolaus just made a workaround so that I load the not-found component for every route instead of redirecting. But if I redirect even after the view is initialized to /404, the icons don't work. 

If however I use even a 0ms timeout, all is good and it works. Makes me think it's something wrong with angular.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with angular. There are often situations, where only timeouts work, because some values are set at the end of the cycle. Timeout of 0 only means finish your current work and then...

Comment: @Nikolaus but in angular ngAfterViewInit is the last lifecycle hook of a components initualisation, so theoretically it is at the end of all app logic and it shouldn't make a difference. redirecting during the 'constructor' of the component -- that code will run much earlier than the other one.

Comment: @MichaelB the last life cycle hook of a component doesn’t have to mean, that something like redirecting is finished, then...it’s all async, you know?